# How to prevent double encryption in Django with Vercel

Tags: django, vercel, url-parameters, url-parsing

I am hosting a django website on Vercel and, both, vercel and Django are encrypting the url.
So, the " " character in the url gets encrypted to "%20" and then django again encrypts it to "%2520", but when decrypting, it decrypts only once.
In my code, I am appending a name which allows " " to be used and that name gets appended to url which later gets used by a function in views.py as pk(not primary key but just a way to get data from the database).
[The problem is clearly seen in the image, url has replaced " " with %20 but django se getting "%2520".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSSv2.png)

So, the problem was just with the " " character, so I removed space character from the name, which solves the problem, but I don't want that to be the solution.

Comment: That's not encryption, that's encoding, in particular https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding